# Any one can show ipn paypal message example to me in amount more than $1000

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Any one can show ipn paypal message example to me in amount more than $1000

i want to know in amount variable it's will show 1000 or 1,000 ( for insert into mysql ) ?

Answer (score 0):

I've run a test and the IPN POST will show the values:

mc_gross=1000.00
payment_gross=**1000.00**

Ref. https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

I hope this answers in full to your question.